# How to get full login name from people picker using object model?

Tags: people-picker

Using the object model, I've retrieved the value from a people picker using standard method, and it returns a string value like this:

> 1#Username

I have a problem with this because I was expecting the full username, including the domain. For example:

> 1#MyCompanyDomain\Username

There must be a way to get the full user and domain name using the object model, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm working with my [PeopleEditor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor.aspx) control this way:

```
foreach (var loginName in peopleEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts.Split(';',','))
{
    SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(loginName);
    // user.LoginName is now returns "domain\login"
}
```

This code works fine for me.

**Update**:

*Note 1*: [EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) will add the user to your site (thanks Ivan Padabed for the comment). In most cases it is ok, but better to remember this.

*Note 2*: This solution in most cases is most preferrable for me, than SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal. At least, because it is avaliable in Sandbox, and ResolvePrincipal isn't.

Comment: Can also use Name instead of loginName in order to get the login portion only.

Comment: Please note that way you all have side effect of adding picked user to the current web!

Comment: @Ivan Padabed thanks for the comment! I've updated the answer.

Comment: This is awesome. Works great. What if I wanted to get the display name as well?

Comment: `user.Name` should do the trick :)

Answer (score 7):

I believe you might also be able to use:

`SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal(webApp, null, login, SPPrincipalType.User, SPPrincipalSource.All, false);`

That said, this is slower than the suggestions using EnsureUser, but does have the benefit of not adding the user to the site, and is a bit more flexible, if you need that sort of thing.

Comment: Very useful comment, thanks! And I'd like to add the link to SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458659.aspx